# Can you alias a user to a temporary @-mention?

Tags: slack, alias

I want to create an alias for our rotating on-call team member. I would like the `@oncall` mention to refer to whomever's on-call every week.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 7):

[Try creating a Slack User Group](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/212906697-Create-a-user-group) and assigning the current on-call user as a member of your new group.

You can then @mention them via their group name, like this: `@current-on-call`

Answer (score 4):

You can check out https://tellspin.app.

It's a Slack app that automatically rotates users within a Slack user group (or alias) based on a schedule. You can have an `@oncall` user group updated daily or weekly with different users depending on how you configure it. It can set overrides too.